# Negative validation set in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, autoencoder

I am training an anomaly detection model using autoencoders in tensorflow. I have got a list of data which are non-anomalous and we are tuning our autoencoder to that training data. After that, when we want to test a data, if it's anomalous or not, we pass it through the autoencoder and it the loss is above a certain threshold, we consider it anomalous.

Now, I have prepared a list of anomalous data(from domain knowledge). However even after much trial and error, my model is not performing well on the anomalous data,i.e, the reconstruction loss is not very significantly high.

**My idea**

I want to use that anomalous data while training that autoencoder, i.e, I want to use it as a validation set and check on each step how well the model performs on the anomalous data, i.e, how big the loss is. However, I am not able to find any resource on how can I do it. If I merely use validation_data in model.fit, it will try to minimize loss on the set, but we want to it to be higher(since it's an anomaly)!

**My solutions**

I tried exploring the *metrics* parameter in model.compile by making my own custom metric. However, I am not able to pass the model in the custom metric.

```
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam',
          loss='mse',metrics=[bad_data_loss])
```

And the custom metric is

```
def bad_data_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    #How to get autoencode(model) in here
```

Because from keras documentation, the metric takes y_true and y_pred only. I can't a way to get get model inside it.

Can anyone give me a hint to solving the above scenario? I have been trying many things but nothing is working.

Comment: I'm confused by "I merely use validation_data in model.fit, it will try to minimize loss on the set, " why do you think it will minimise loss on validation_data. It minimises loss on training data

Comment: @CAFEBABE I want the reconstruction loss to be low on non-anomalous data(training data) and high on anomalous data(validation set). If a model is training correctly, the loss should decrease on non-anomalous data and increase on anomalous data. However, after each epoch, if validation loss increases, tensroflow will think of it as overfitting on training data, which I don't want. It should see loss increasing on validation set and decreasing on training set as a postive thing(model is getting trained correctly).